# json response not working in IE

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

This is my code. This is for pass values using json to jsoncall.php file and need to get the response.

```
 var url = 'jsoncall.php';  
    var calltype = "signin";    
    parameters = 'call='+calltype;
    var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
    var pass = document.getElementById('password').value; 
    var serverurl = document.getElementById('s_url').value;
    var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;

    if(email == "") {
        alert("Plese enter your email address!");
        return false;   
    }else if(email != ""){

       if(reg.test(email) == false) {    
          alert('Invalid Email Address!');
          return false;
       }
    }else if(pass == "") {
        alert('Please enter your password!');
        return false;   
    }

    setTimeout( function() {
        jQuery.getJSON(serverurl+url+'?callback=?',
            {call:calltype, txtEmail: email, txtPassword: pass, login: ""}, 
                function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    //alert(data.result);
                    if(data.result == 0){                       
                        alert("Invalid email or password!");
                        return false;
                    }else {                        
                        window.location = data.result; 
                    }

            });
      }, 100);
```

This work in Crome, Firefox. But this does not work in IE. When I press f12 and got the developer tool in IE then it start to work in IE. Otherwise it won't work. Thank you for your help.

Comment: BTW, the `parameters` variable doesn't have a `var` before it - you are leaking a global.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `console.log` is only available after you start developer tools. You can absorb the error with a try/catch block or create a dummy `console` object if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you very much. I removed the console.log from my code. Now it works fine. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Comment the line `console.log` and it will work. Its better to use `alert` in `IE`. But still if you want to use `console` please refer this http://www.we-are-gurus.com/blog/1578-avoid-console-log-error-with-ie